# Once uninstalled, is data stored by an app on SD card also removed simultaneously?

Tags: sd-card, uninstallation, storage

As an example - newer games once downloaded and installed from the Market (Play Store), also subsequently download extra data to a user's SD card. When one opts to uninstall said app/game, is the additional downloaded data also deleted off the SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where game has downloaded data.

If its under `<sdcard_root>/Android/data/<package_name>`, the data will be cleared.

If its under some custom directory like `<sdcard_root>/GameName/`, the data will not be cleared.

Comment: So the uninstall is a function of the app developer's ability or is it an internal Android function?

Comment: @Sparx There's no uninstaller concept in Android to avoid programmer's mistakes.. So, its handled by Android.. Here, situation isn't like Windows when Add Remove program just triggers uninstaller..

Comment: @Sparx You can't find a program's entry in Add Remove program, if there's no uninstaller registered with system. But, in Android.... Have you ever seen an app which isn't listed in Settings? Do you think all Droid dev are smart? This makes Android great... :)

Comment: In that case, shouldn't the data also be wiped no matter where it's kept, especially if Android is handling things - after all it's data associated with an uninstalled app..?

Comment: @Sparx Ok.. You've taken a photo using a camera app (which has written the image in a file on SD). Do you like Android to remove those images too, when you uninstall the app?

Comment: @Sparx It's standard set by Android to avoid the problem I mentioned. Technically, Android doesn't monitor such things..

Comment: The photo may have been taken by the app, but that is user data and so mustn't be included in an uninstall. I hope you understand what I'm referring to - data >>installed<< by the app. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: The photo was an example.. There's no way for system to know the difference between data. e. g. A text editor can save a text file created by you as well as a text file having its configuration.

Comment: Even with true "Artificial Intelligence", there're chances of mistakes.. :)